# Explanation for this Limitation of 1-Order Logic Concerning Supremum

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, predicate-logic

In some book I found the statement that it is not possible in the predicate calsulus to express the sentence, that every bounded nonempty subset of an ordered field has a supremum. I thought that could be expressed as follows, for a subset $X \subset K$ of some ordered field $K$

\begin{align}
\left[ X\subset K \land X \neq \emptyset \land \forall x\in X\ \exists a\in K(x<a) \right] \to
\exists s\in K\ \forall y\in K\left(( \forall x\in X\ x<y)\to s<y \right)
\end{align}
What is wrong about that ?

Comment: The point is that the $X$ in your formula is not a first order variable, since it ranges over subsets. The statement you want to formalize contains the phrase "every bounded subset", that's literally a quantification over subsets, which is not admissible in 1st order. (however, whereas in the title of your question you talk about 1st order, in the text  you speak about "predicate logic", which is more general if I'm not mistaken, and contains "higher order logic", where quantification over subsets is admissible)

Comment: @JonasFrey In my experience "predicate logic" is almost always (but not quite always) used to refer to first-order logic(s) specifically.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. Yes in Wiki the predicate and first-order-logic are on two different pages, so it seems the the predicate logic is the more general one. The book that I refered to above doesn't seem to have made this distinction clear.

Comment: @NoahSchweber Thanks, I was never sure about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In first-order logic (as opposed to [higher-order logics](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-higher-order/)) we can only quantify over **individual objects** in the domain in question, rather than e.g. subsets of the domain or functions on the domain. So if we're working in the context of ordered fields, the sentence you've written is **not first order**.

---

Although not directly related to your question, it's worth saying a bit more about the consequences of this limitation on quantification - which turn out to be extremely significant! The two most important are the **compactness** and **Löwenheim-Skolem** *(especially [**downward**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%B6wenheim%E2%80%93Skolem_theorem#Theorem) Löwenheim-Skolem, the upward part being a corollary of compactness)* theorems:

- [**Compactness**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compactness_theorem): if $\Gamma$ is any first-order theory and every finite subset of $\Gamma$ is satisfiable, then $\Gamma$ is satisfiable.
- [**Löwenheim-Skolem**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%B6wenheim%E2%80%93Skolem_theorem): if $\Gamma$ is any first-order theory in a language of size $\kappa$, and $\Gamma$ has at least one infinite model, then $\Gamma$ has at least one infinite model of every infinite cardinality $\ge\kappa$. In particular, if $\Gamma$ is countable then $\Gamma$ has models of every infinite cardinality.

It turns out that in a precise sense [we can't strengthen first-order logic *at all* without losing at least one of these properties](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lindstr%C3%B6m%27s_theorem). In particular, second-order logic fails both properties. (The proof of this is a bit lengthy, especially in the case of Löwenheim-Skolem if you're not already familiar with some set theory; however, I can add them if you're interested.)

Comment: Could you perhaps explain more explicitly how would a quantification over subsets look like ? So above the formula should have been preceded by $ \forall P : x \in X \leftrightarrow P(x)$, or sth like that...where $P$ is unary relation

Comment: @Physor No, you have to quantify over $X$. The point is that subsets of the field are not individual objects in the field (they're not field elements), so you can't even *refer* to a specific subset of the field: all the language of fields can directly refer to are elements of the field and the field operations. You have to quantify over them ("All subsets have suprema"), and that quantification is second-order.

Comment: Of course, this doesn't mean that first-order set theory is perfectly capable of formulating the property in question. So the statement that the OP has quoted appears to be slightly over-simplified.